# refresh rate of monitor resets to 60hz after each reboot

Tags: 10.10, xorg, nvidia

I'm using ubuntu 10.10 64 bit. It started to revert the refresh rate of my monitor to 60hz, each and every time I log on. I change it back in nvidia panel, save it to X config file, but it just doesn't last. Oh, I set every time to 85hz. As noted below, this is the part in my x config file

```
Section "Screen" 
 Removed Option "metamodes" "1024x768_85.00 " 
 Removed Option "metamodes" "1024x768_85 +0+0" > 
 Removed Option "metamodes" "1024x768 +0+0; 1024x768_85 +0+0" 
Identifier "Screen0" 
Device "Device0" 
Monitor "Monitor0" 
DefaultDepth 24 
Option "TwinView" "0"
Option "metamodes" "1024x768_85 +0+0; 1024x768 +0+0" 
SubSection "Display" Depth 24 
EndSubSection"
```

Comment: @Castro: thanks for the edit, I'm a complete noob in these respect =)

Comment: so, i've updated my system with terminal apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, and it's working again. I do not know what was wrong in the first place, but just to say how I resolved this issue

Answer (score 2):

Did you launch the nvidia tool with super user privileges?

I had a similar issue where the tool launched as a normal user did not issue any error at saving time, but the saving was incomplete because of access right.

Launching the tool with super user privileges solved my problem.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: sudo nvidia-settings

Comment: It didn't help. I still get to 60hz whenever I boot up

Comment: so, does anyone know other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `/etx/X11/xorg.conf` file. Specifically at the mode string in the Screen Section.

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Device        "NVIDIA Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5200]"
    Monitor        "CM752ET"
    DefaultDepth    16
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth        16
        Modes      "1024x768_75.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Does your specify the refresh after the resolution? (eg does it explicitly say `_85.00`?)

I had some issues a long while back that were fixed by setting the mode string up. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: this is my config file

Comment: @Habkost Don't add the info in a comment, edit your question to add more detail.